# 'input string was not in a correct format' - can anybody help me?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
double buy, sell, qt, tsell, tbuy, trev;
private void pro_cal()
{
    sell = Convert.ToDouble(edt_sell.Text);
    buy = Convert.ToDouble(edt_buy.Text);
    qt = Convert.ToDouble(edt_qt.Value);
    tsell = sell * qt;
    tbuy = buy * qt;
    trev = tsell - tbuy;
    lblTbuy.Text = tbuy.ToString();
    lblTsell.Text = tsell.ToString();
    lblTRev.Text = trev.ToString();
}
```

I tried `double.tryparse` but that doesn't work.

[image: when I empty out my textbox here is what I get!]

Comment: `double.TryParse()` does *work*. *Try* again.

Comment: You can also use NumericUpDown Controls or test the content of your TextBoxes beforehand. -- You should avoid `Convert.ToSomething()` anyway.

Comment: Obviously, the content of the `edt_buy` input cannot be parsed to a double. And what do you mean by `double.TryParse` doesn't work. It works perfectly fine if you use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet so I'll do it here: *please, show us the string you're typing*

Maybe the string has a space to you could use Trim() to remove them

However, what I think is the most probably thing, is that the method is trying to parse it with another internationalization. For example, we use our number like *3,100.82* where the comma is to distinguish between thousands, millions or billions and the dot is to distinguish decimals, **however**, in other countries they write the numbers like *3.100,82*... it's exactly the opposite.

**To solve that, you have to add the culture info to the method, like this:**

```
buy = Convert.ToDouble(edt_buy.Text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

*That may work, but please add to your post how you wrote the number since I may be wrong*